Loaded 0 blocks during reindex
My node is busy with a -reindex. In the debug.log file I see lines like the following:
Reindexing block file blk02620.dat...
Loaded 438 blocks from external file in 7133ms

This seems normal, however, there are a lot of lines like this:
Reindexing block file blk02775.dat...
Loaded 0 blocks from external file in 714ms

I checked the file size of blk02775.dat and it is 128M like all the other *.dat files. How can it be that the file contains zero blocks?
